# StoreKit - format of clientToken for requestPersonalizationToken?

Tags: ios, storekit, apple-music, apple-musickit

In the sparse [Apple StoreKit Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH40-SW1) it mentions using a `clientToken` to request a `personalizationToken` from a device via [`requestPersonalizationToken`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skcloudservicecontroller/2835181-requestpersonalizationtoken).

There is no accompanying documentation to describe what this token should be. I had assumed that it should take the form of a developer [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) token but that does not appear to work, giving the error `SKErrorDomain code 8` with a `nil` token response.

I know that the token works for a regular call to the Music API and so assume it is of the correct format for a `developerToken`.

I am aware that Apple are not giving out tokens via [`requestUserTokenForDeveloperToken`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skcloudservicecontroller/2909079-requestusertokenfordevelopertoke) until later in the year but assumed that [`requestPersonalizationToken`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skcloudservicecontroller/2835181-requestpersonalizationtoken) was the current (although already deprecated) method until iOS 11 is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any others that hit this thread.

Yes, the token is the same format. Apple have recently pushed an update out that resolves the issues that I was encountering. The exact same code now successfully retrieves a UserToken.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Music sample code](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/Interacting-with-Apple-Music-Content.zip) is using "requestPersonalizationToken forClientToken" for pre iOS 11 devices. The sample is passing MusicKit [developerToken](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/SetUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH2-SW1) in JWT form for client token.

Comment: Thanks Bahri. That is the source code that I am looking at but it doesn't work. I have known there to be errors in Apples Source code listing in the past and wanted to find a definitive location that points to the token. E.g. the Token is named differently to the iOS11 equivalent (clientToken vs developerToken).

Comment: You are right Moss, having it in the sample code does not have to mean it is the correct way. After your comment, I just checked the sample code on two iOS 10.3 devices and saw requestPersonalizationTokenForClientToken call is ending with error (SKErrorDomain, code:8).